# django error, "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing"

Tags: django, django-models

I am having an error when i create an object with data from a csv file, the error is:

"The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing."

it seems to come from the get_or_create line. i have tried to slice all the querysets in the function but this has not fixed the problem. and i already know all the model fields exist and are correct with my models.py

```
            contracts = Contract.objects.filter(contract_id=row[2])
            if not contracts:  
                continue

            new_contract = contracts.first()

            logger.info(new_contract.contract_id)

            _, created = Job.objects.get_or_create(contract=new_contract, 
                                                   order_type = str(row[3])[:0], 
                                                   description_of_works  = str(row[4]), 
                                                   added_on = date_time_obj,
                                                   date_raised = date_time_obj,
                                                   draughtsman = base_user.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=issuer_str[0:4]),
                                                   status = job_status, #IDFK
                                                   comment = str(row[8]),
                                                   design_required = design_req,
                                                   designer = str(row[10])).first()
```

i have checked other questions of the same topic and they didnt have any solutions.
Any help is appreciated.

edit:
this is the traceback from the container

```
web_1 | Traceback (most recent call last):

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 339, in thread_handler

web_1 | raise exc_info[1]

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 38, in inner

web_1 | response = await get_response(request)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 233, in _get_response_async

web_1 | response = await wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 304, in __call__

web_1 | ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 442, in wait_for

web_1 | return await fut

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/current_thread_executor.py", line 23, in run

web_1 | result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 343, in thread_handler

web_1 | return func(*args, **kwargs)

web_1 | File "./Trackers_App/views.py", line 224, in test_zone

web_1 | import_csv()

web_1 | File "./Trackers_App/views.py", line 1747, in import_csv

web_1 | _, created = Job.objects.get_or_create(contract=new_contract,

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method

web_1 | return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 573, in get_or_create

web_1 | return self.get(**kwargs), False

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 425, in get

web_1 | num = len(clone)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__

web_1 | self._fetch_all()

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all

web_1 | self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__

web_1 | results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cachalot/monkey_patch.py", line 29, in inner

web_1 | return original(compiler, *args, **kwargs)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cachalot/monkey_patch.py", line 79, in inner

web_1 | cache_key = cachalot_settings.CACHALOT_QUERY_KEYGEN(compiler)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cachalot/utils.py", line 76, in get_query_cache_key

web_1 | sql, params = compiler.as_sql()

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 513, in as_sql

web_1 | where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 430, in compile

web_1 | sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 81, in as_sql

web_1 | sql, params = compiler.compile(child)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 430, in compile

web_1 | sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 132, in as_sql

web_1 | return super().as_sql(compiler, connection)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 302, in as_sql

web_1 | return super().as_sql(compiler, connection)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 181, in as_sql

web_1 | rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 284, in process_rhs

web_1 | raise ValueError(

web_1 | ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

web_1 | 2021-02-23 11:15:29,536 ERROR Internal Server Error: /trackers/test_zone/

web_1 | Traceback (most recent call last):

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 339, in thread_handler

web_1 | raise exc_info[1]

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 38, in inner

web_1 | response = await get_response(request)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 233, in _get_response_async

web_1 | response = await wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 304, in __call__

web_1 | ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 442, in wait_for

web_1 | return await fut

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/current_thread_executor.py", line 23, in run

web_1 | result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 343, in thread_handler

web_1 | return func(*args, **kwargs)

web_1 | File "./Trackers_App/views.py", line 224, in test_zone

web_1 | import_csv()

web_1 | File "./Trackers_App/views.py", line 1747, in import_csv

web_1 | _, created = Job.objects.get_or_create(contract=new_contract,

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method

web_1 | return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 573, in get_or_create

web_1 | return self.get(**kwargs), False

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 425, in get

web_1 | num = len(clone)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__

web_1 | self._fetch_all()

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all

web_1 | self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__

web_1 | results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cachalot/monkey_patch.py", line 29, in inner

web_1 | return original(compiler, *args, **kwargs)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cachalot/monkey_patch.py", line 79, in inner

web_1 | cache_key = cachalot_settings.CACHALOT_QUERY_KEYGEN(compiler)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cachalot/utils.py", line 76, in get_query_cache_key

web_1 | sql, params = compiler.as_sql()

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 513, in as_sql

web_1 | where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 430, in compile

web_1 | sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 81, in as_sql

web_1 | sql, params = compiler.compile(child)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 430, in compile

web_1 | sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 132, in as_sql

web_1 | return super().as_sql(compiler, connection)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 302, in as_sql

web_1 | return super().as_sql(compiler, connection)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 181, in as_sql

web_1 | rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)

web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 284, in process_rhs

web_1 | raise ValueError(

web_1 | ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

Comment: `draughtsman = base_user.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=issuer_str[0:4])` is the culprit, since that is a `QuerySet`, so a *collection*, not a *single* `base_user` object.

Comment: that solved it, could you make this comment an answer so i can mark it as solved, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is the line:

```
    draughtsman = base_user.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=issuer_str[0:4]),
```

is the culprit, since that is a `QuerySet`, so a *collection*, not a *single* `base_user` object. You can use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) or work with [**`.first()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first) to obtain an object (the two are not completely equivalent, for more information, visit the documentation).

You thus should pass a `base_user` *object*, for example with:

```
    draughtsman = base_user.objects.get(first_name__icontains=issuer_str[0:4]),
```